# OxyPlot WPF Tooltip and crosshair colours

Tags: wpf, colors, tooltip, oxyplot

I am plotting some simple line series on an oxyplot chart, using WPF. When I click on a point on a line series the colour of the tooltip is a horrible green and the crosshair colour is black. I would like to change these.

```
                <oxy:Plot x:Name="SliceStatsChart" Title="Slice Stats">
                    <oxy:Plot.Series>
                        <oxy:LineSeries Title="MaxV"/>
                        <oxy:LineSeries Title="MinV"/>
                        <oxy:LineSeries Title="AvgV"/>
                        <oxy:LineSeries Title="StdDev"/>
                    </oxy:Plot.Series>
                    <oxy:Plot.Axes>
                        <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Left" TicklineColor="White" Title= "Log10(V)"/>
                        <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Bottom" TicklineColor="White" Title= "Slice No"/>    
                    </oxy:Plot.Axes>
```

Please could someone advice me how to modify the colours.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The cursor is named "Tracker" in OxyPlot. It's appearance can be modified by editing the DefaultTrackerTemplate. This example modifies the tracker control's background color and the color of the crosshair lines but of course there are much more ways to customize it:

```
<oxy:Plot x:Name="SliceStatsChart" Title="Slice Stats">

    <oxy:PlotView.DefaultTrackerTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <oxy:TrackerControl Position="{Binding Position}" LineStroke="Red" Background="GhostWhite">
                <oxy:TrackerControl.Content>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5" />
                </oxy:TrackerControl.Content>
            </oxy:TrackerControl>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </oxy:PlotView.DefaultTrackerTemplate>

    <oxy:Plot.Series>
        <oxy:LineSeries Title="MaxV"/>
        <oxy:LineSeries Title="MinV"/>
        <oxy:LineSeries Title="AvgV"/>
        <oxy:LineSeries Title="StdDev"/>
    </oxy:Plot.Series>
    <oxy:Plot.Axes>
        <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Left" TicklineColor="White" Title="Log10(V)"/>
        <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Bottom" TicklineColor="White" Title= "Slice No"/>    
    </oxy:Plot.Axes>
</oxy:Plot>
```